# Is to a preposition in that case

Tags: gerunds

The crazy thing is this record took a total of 9 days from initial idea **to having** a pressed record in our hands

Why "to having" and not "to have"?  Is it the same as in" I am not used to doing it. In this case" to "is a preposition, we can take off the word"having" the sentence is still understandable.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a gerund as a noun
for example : *"explaining"* can be used to mean *"explanation"*

**To + gerund**
The gerund here is used to indicate the state of something .
 In this case , you can look at what follows the preposition **(to)** as one block .

*examples :*

- I went from **waking up late** to **waking up early .**
  *(I went from the state of walking up late to the state of waking up early)*
- This is the first step to **becoming what I've always dreamt of** .
  *(This is the first step to the state of becoming what I've always dreamt of)*
- They were on the road to **building the world's first self-driving car** .
  *(They were close to the state of successfully building the car)*

**To + infinitive**
It's used to indicate the purpose of doing something .
*for example :* I went to the park to see a friend of mine .
= I went to the park **in order to** see a friend of mine .

Looking at the former examples from this perceptive :

- I went from waking up late to wake up early .
  *(although the sentence structure is wrong now , it means that you were waking up late **in order to** wake up early , which doesn't make sense)*
- This is the first step to become what I've always dreamt of .
  *(this means that the step became what you've always dreamt of , which doesn't make sense)*
- They were on the road to build the world's first self-driving car .
  *(this means they were literally traveling **in order to** build the car)*

Answer (score 0):

To + have is for a purpose. I went to school to study. [purpose]

To is a function word here. It tells us the purpose of why the person went to school.

**To start something** and **go to some point**: having a pressed record in our hands. To is a preposition in this case.

Here: having a pressed record in our hands is "a state of affairs" or result.

From and To are prepositions: going **from** the initial whatever **to** having whatever.

Comment: thanks for your answer but you don't reply to my question is to a preposition in this case that is what I think

Comment: @user5577 Actually, I did indirectly. But now I have fixed it to spell it out.